# What is the maximum/default width of an image tag in a question or answer?

Tags: support, design

This image (original) is large 1440px.
[image: 1440px large image to demonstrate lenght of images in posts]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current maximum image width and maximum post width?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331439/what-is-the-current-maximum-image-width-and-maximum-post-width)

Answer (score 7):

Image width is limited with a `max-width` of 630px, so it doesn't overflow:

```
.post-text img {
    max-width: 630px;
}
```